# How to set the page source in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

When using python-selenium and loading a web page I can get the source as follows:

```
webdriver.page_source
```

Is there a way to *set* the page source?

I want to 'read' the html from a file and perform a location action on it, i.e. something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_source(open('my_file.html'))
driver.find_element((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='create']//input"))
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just open this local file? Something like `webdriver.get("file:///path/my_file.html")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open the file directly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('file:///' + os.getcwd() +'/my_file.html')
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='create']//input")
driver.quit()
```

P.S. I recall that this doesn't work on IE. It works fine on Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement something like below:

```
# Get "html" element
current_html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html")
# Get "body" element from saved HTML doc
saved_doc = open("my_file.html")
new_body = saved_doc.read().split("<html>")[-1].split("</html>")[0]
# Replace "body" of current page with "body" of saved page
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1]", current_html, new_body)

saved_doc.close()
```